# What are the values of b such that the matrix [(1,1)(b,1)] is invertible mod 26.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

What are the values of b such that the matrix [(1,1)(b,1)] is invertible mod 26.

I figured that the matrix is only invertible if its determinant and the n value 26 's gcd is 1, meaning they are relatively prime.

So, det(matrix) = (1-b), and then for all values gcd((1-b),n) = 1 would conclude that that's the values of b that are valid.

But would this yield an unlimited amount of values of b?

Comment: Only a finite number (12) of congruence classes modulo $26$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have $b-1\ne 0 \pmod{26}$ and  the restrictions $b-1\ne 2n$  and $b-1\ne 13m$ because $b-1\ne 0\pmod{2}$ and $b-1\ne 0\pmod{13}$. In other words $b$ even and $b-1$ not multiple of $13$.